# Xcode 5.1 Simulator missing (Unity developed game)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, unity-game-engine

I've developed a simple pong game in Unity, and I want to port it to iOS. When I try and run it in Xcode I get:
"No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version. Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination."

I've searched online, and the fix was to choose an iOS simulator as the destination. But, I'm only given 'iOS Device' as an option.

Any help is appreciated,
Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: Xcode 6 saw a major change to the iOS Simulator.  I suggest you update to Xcode 6.1 and try again.  If you are stuck on Xcode 5.1.1 (eg: stuck on Mountain Lion), then please provide some additional information.  Specifically: what deployment target do you have set, what are your build settings for valid architectures and architectures?  Please show a screenshot of the run destinations menu.

Comment: Hi Jeremy. I'm new to Xcode, so I'm not familiar with the build settings. I've basically used the 'switch platform' option in Unity to convert it to the iOS platform. The screenshot of the run destinations menu: http://i.imgur.com/iRjCZ4L.png . Screenshot of when I run it: http://i.imgur.com/ISd3cHr.png

Comment: Can you upgrade to Xcode 6.1.1?  The new version of Xcode includes CoreSimulator which is quite different (internally) than what was in Xcode 5.1.  I'll be able to help you more if you try a newer Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you wanna use the simulator you should just go to build settings >select player settings>other settings>optimization>SDK Version and select simulatorSDK :P hope that helped..

Comment: This comment is flat out wrong.  This is not necessary.

Comment: Well it's probably the right answer this thing happened to me before well if she has done that already she should try to plug and unplug the cable and make the device trust the computer and maybe there's a problem in the cable ... But i believe it's most likely the first case

Comment: Thank you, the simulator works now. :) Also, if I decide that I want to release the game in the App store, would I have to go back into Unity, change the SDK version, and then change the code again to suit the touch screen playability?

Comment: @user3146598 the physical device has no impact on the sim.

Comment: @Tsubasa Just set the SDK to the default value (delete your override) and edit the deployment target to be no less than the deployment target used to build Unity (reference Unity's release notes).  You should not need to override the SDK in build settings at all.  That will likely lead to more trouble down the road.

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia I've set the SDK back to default value (I can't run the game anymore), and I'm assuming by deployment target you mean 'Target iOS Version'? When you say 'to be no less than the deployment target used to build Unity', should I put the value to 'Unknown' then?

Comment: No.  It should bot be unknown.  I suggest you use 8.0 if you don't know what Unity was built with.